# I want to know why I get that error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, express

**code of `app.js`**
[code of `app.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ujp.png)

**code of `index.js`**
[code of `index.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP9f3.png)

**folder structure**
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoGuo.png)
**this is the error that I get in the terminal:**
**

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\onli\Desktop\mssqlRest\src\app' imported from C:\Users\onli\Desktop\mssqlRest\index.js
Did you mean to import ../src/app.js?
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:271:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:694:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:805:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:72:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:71:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**

Comment: `Did you mean to import ../src/app.js?`

Comment: I am getting the same kind of error.